# In PL/SQL can I set a variable dynamically?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

In Oracle 12c R2, I have a function which receives a row type as a variable. In the function I want to read a table which contains a column name and a value, I want to then populate the row type variable passed in using the column name and the data from the table I read.

Here is a simplistic idea of what I want to do;

```
CREATE TABLE table_to_be_updated
(
  key_value number,
  cola varchar2(2),
  colb varchar2(2),
  colc varchar2(2),
  cold varchar2(2),
  cole varchar2(2),
  colf varchar2(2)
);

CREATE TABLE table_default_value
(
  default_stuff number,
  column_name varchar(30),
  column_default_value varchar2(2)
);

function do_defaults(in_table table_to_be_updated%rowtype, in_value number) return table_to_be_updated%rowtype
is
  out_table table_to_be_updated%rowtype := in_table;
  cursor my_curs
  is
    select * from table_default_value where default_stuff = in_value;
begin
  for default_rec in my_curs
  loop
    out_table.[default_rec.column_name] := default_rec.column_default_value
  end loop;
  return out_table;
end;
insert into table_default_value (default_stuff,column_name,column_default_value) values (1,'cola','xx'));
insert into table_default_value (default_stuff,column_name,column_default_value) values (1,'colc','aa'));
insert into table_default_value (default_stuff,column_name,column_default_value) values (1,'cole','bb'));
```

In the line;

```
out_table.[default_rec.column_name] := [default_rec.column_default_value]
```

[default_rec.column_name] would be the column name, from the cursor, in out_table name I want to move data to.

and

[default_rec.column_default_value] is the value from the cursor I want to move into that column.

I suspect that what I want to do is impossible in PL/SQL, but I thought I'd ask.

There are other ways to accomplish updating the table directly, specifically using dynamic SQL with execute immediate, but I have a number of similar tables which all need to have the same things done to them, and I would prefer a single function to work on a record and then pass it back to have the calling routine update the proper table.

Comment: Hmm, I would try to do this with an associative array (index by varchar2) as the parameter instead of your %rowtype record which I don't think will work. And then just use `default_rec.column_name` as the key, e.g. `out_table(default_rec.column_name) := default_rec.column_default_value;`

Comment: In some languages (usually weakly typed languages) you can treat record data types as associative arrays, but PL/SQL (a mostly strongly typed language) is not one of those languages.

Comment: I could create an associative array from the DB, but then the question is how to get the data from the associative array into the %rowtype variable.

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the best I can come up with;***

```
function do_defaults(in_table table_to_be_updated%rowtype, in_value number) return table_to_be_updated%rowtype
is
  TYPE DEFAULT_TYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2)
       INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
  DEFAULT_ARRAY DEFAULT_TYPE;

  out_table table_to_be_updated%rowtype := in_table;
  cursor my_curs
  is
    select * from table_default_value where default_stuff = in_value;
begin
  DEFAULT_ARRAY('cola') := null;
  DEFAULT_ARRAY('colb') := null;
  DEFAULT_ARRAY('colc') := null;
  DEFAULT_ARRAY('cold') := null;
  DEFAULT_ARRAY('cole') := null;
  DEFAULT_ARRAY('colf') := null;
  for default_rec in my_curs
  loop
    DEFAULT_ARRAY(default_rec.column_name) := default_rec.column_default_value
  end loop;
  out_table.cola := DEFAULT_ARRAY('cola');
  out_table.colb := DEFAULT_ARRAY('colb');
  out_table.colc := DEFAULT_ARRAY('colc');
  out_table.cold := DEFAULT_ARRAY('cold');
  out_table.cole := DEFAULT_ARRAY('cole');
  out_table.colf := DEFAULT_ARRAY('colf');
  return out_table;
end;
```